# How to access public contact folder in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to access the content of a public contact folder.

It's destination isn't on my computer. My normal `olookfldr.Folders("FolderName")` won't find it.

I looked on Microsoft support but have yet to implement any of the contact there.

```vb
Public Sub OpenSharedHolidayCalendar()
    Dim oNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim oFolder As folder
    Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNamespace.OpenSharedFolder("webcal:\\_PUBLICA-AM")
    oFolder.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that a Public Folders store contact folder? Or is it in a delegate mailbox of another user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.OpenSharedFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.opensharedfolder) method to open a shared folder referenced through a URL or file name.

Also you may consider using the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Contacts folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```